# Difference between "applyTo" and "contentEl" in extJS

Tags: extjs

What is the difference between `applyTo` and `contentEl` in extJS? They are two config properties of the panel.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`applyTo` renders the panel into a target element (the panel body could still contain any content), `contentEl` uses the target element as its body content (the panel could still be rendered to any other element).  The two methods are unrelated.

**Edit**: Just a note that as of Ext 4.0+ the `applyTo` config no longer exists. As time went on, the declarative / progressive enhancement strategy became less viable for Ext (it never was fully supported in all components anyway), and they finally stopped supporting it.  You would always use [`renderTo`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.AbstractComponent-cfg-renderTo) now (to render programmatically to a target element), whereas [`contentEl`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.AbstractComponent-cfg-contentEl) is still valid and still indicates the element from which to take content and add it into the panel's body.`contentEl` is most useful when you have some existing HTML on the page that you want to display inside a Panel component without having to reproduce the content markup in JS code.

While I'm here, I suppose I'll clarify something else... It's important to understand that `renderTo` is typically only used by the top-most container in an application layout.  All child components should always be added as [`items`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.container.AbstractContainer-cfg-items) to a Container -- rendering child components directly to a target element via `renderTo` means that those components will not participate in the Ext-managed layout system, which you typically do NOT want in an application.

Another difference is that every component in Ext supports `renderTo`, but only certain components (most usefully Panel) will honor `contentEl` in a meaningful way.  Even though `contentEl` is defined on `AbstractComponent`, most components are not designed to handle arbitrary HTML content.

Comment: so, the applyTo equals to 'renderTo"?

Comment: applyTo assumes that the existing content supplies structural markup expected by Ext and renders the component on top of that.  renderTo simply treats the existing element as a parent container to render into.  The docs are pretty clear on what these do, you should review them more closely.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, applyTo uses the specified element as the main element of the Component, while contentEl is only for Panels that simply moves the specified element into the body of the Panel when the Panel is rendered to use as the content!