# Ext js - diffrence between applyTo and renderTo

Tags: javascript, extjs

I've started to learn Ext js and I couldn't find any difference between applyTo and renderTo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3929370/difference-between-applyto-and-contentel-in-extjs) is very helpful in explaining the difference between the two and more...